# Why does winfo_width() return a larger size of button widget than the size of what it exactly looks like?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want buttons/labels in the same column will share the same width with a specific/first button/label. The problem is winfo_width() seems not to return what I want. The return value of winfo_width() is multiple times the button.

I don't want to make width fixed by a number I select. Thus, I did not find a solution to my problem.

Here is part of my code:

```
button_1.update_idletasks()
print(button_1.winfo_width())
new_label = Label(frame_1, bg=  "#8432C7", width = 30, height = 5)
new_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```

Since I don't have 10 reputation to post images, here is the link for the generated interface:

[image]

If you could see the above image, you should find the lower label (width = 30) is larger than the upper button (width = 157 ?).

But, according to my attempts, 157 seems not to be the width of button_1. I feel confused about what exactly winfo_width() returns here. Thus, I want to know what winfo_width() returns (why winfo_width() return 157 which should be a smaller number than 30) and how to get the exact width of the button.

I am stuck here for an hour since I just started to learn Tkinter recently. 
Thanks in advance for anyone who can give me suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun fact: you don't have to bother with this at all.

Just pass `sticky` when you `grid` your widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button_1 = tk.Button(root,text="button_1")
button_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="ew")
new_label = tk.Label(root, bg=  "#8432C7", height = 5)
new_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="ew")

root.mainloop()
```

Then your columns will be auto-fit and scaled to the same size.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the width used in the arguments to create a button are in different units than what tkinter uses.

> From the [Documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) of a `Button` in tkinter. Width is `The width of the button. If the button displays text, the size is given in text units. If the button displays an image, the size is given in pixels (or screen units). If the size is omitted, or zero, it is calculated based on the button contents. (width/Width)`

You will find that if you use tkinters `.place()` to set a size, the size that `.winfo_width()` returns will be the same.

For example:

```py
button_1.update_idletasks()
print(button_1.winfo_width())
new_label = Label(frame_1, bg=  "#8432C7")
new_label.place(x=40, y=0, width=157, height=20)
```

You will find that the `new_label` will now have the same width as the button